# I have a wordlist and a text I want to match and assign elements with attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two XML files, one is the word-database and one is a text I want to match with the database. I have tried several approaches of which none achieved my desired result.

Say we have these two files:

database.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wordbase>
    <word>
        <paragraph>1</paragraph>
        <line>1</line>
        <wordno>1</wordno>
        <trans>hello</trans>
    </word>
    <word>
        <paragraph>2</paragraph>
        <line>1</line>
        <wordno>2</wordno>
        <trans>example</trans>
    </word>
    <word>
        <paragraph>2</paragraph>
        <line>1</line>
        <wordno>2</wordno>
        <trans>this</trans>
    </word>    
</wordbase>
```

and this second file text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p>
        <l>hello</l>
    </p>
    <p>
        <l>this example</l>
    </p>
</root>
```

As a result I want to get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <p>
        <l><w paragraph="1" line="1" wordno="1">hello</w></l>
    </p>
    <p>
        <l><w paragraph="2" line="1" wordno="1">this</w> <w paragraph="2" line="1" wordno="2">example</w></l>
    </p>
</root>
```

The XSL does not need to count the paragraphs or lines. I just want it to go into the file test.xml and check the words. It reads "hello", goes to database.xml, checks for "hello" and assigns the attributes paragraph, line, wordno it finds there.

I can't really contribute sample XSL, and I know that this is bad form, but I did not achieve much. I had several approaches, but gained nothing from it. I tried it with the document-function, xsl:sort, xsl:analzye-string, xsl:for-each group, xsl:tokenize. I guess the answer lies somewhere in those approaches.

I hope someone can help me out.

Thanks and good-bye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start from this code snippet, and adapt it according to your tokenization rules (it works with your sample):

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
  <xsl:param name="tokens" />
  <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before($tokens, ' ')" />
  <xsl:if test="$token != ''">
    <xsl:variable name="word" select="document('wordbase.xml')/wordbase/word[trans = $token]" />        
    <w paragraph="{$word/paragraph}" line="{$word/line}" wordno="{$word/wordno}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
    </w>
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
      <xsl:with-param name="tokens" select="substring-after($tokens, ' ')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="l">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
      <xsl:with-param name="tokens" select="concat(text(), ' ')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```